# Is it possible to change a vote on an answer from the question being edited?

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers, editing, voting

I down-voted [This Answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/65370/23186), as at the time I felt that it didn't actually answer the question as it was asked.

Now that the question has been edited, this answer is a valid answer and not deserving of my down-vote.

Is it possible to implement that votes on answers can be changed on the question itself being edited as well as the voted answer being edited?

Comment: The [same](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/24437/276044) request has been [made](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/34437/276044) on MSE a [few](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32266/276044) times [before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104451/allow-changing-votes-on-answer-if-question-has-been-edited?lq=1).

Comment: (I think it's a *good* request, mind you.)