# Should we be able to retract answer downvotes after a question is reopened?

Tags: feature-request, voting, down-votes

in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/164627), the querent didn't originally attach a system, and someone answered before the question was closed.

I downvoted the answer because we didn't have the appropriate information.

Everything is well now with the question and I want to upvote it, but I can't until the question is edited.

What should be the solution to this problem? (and should this be a main meta question?)

Comment: the answer  has been edited ...

Comment: Related: [Editing an answer to change a mistaken vote](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8815/52137), [Is it OK to edit an outdated answer to facilitate a vote change?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8960/52137), [Is it possible to change a vote on an answer from the question being edited?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5662/52137)

Comment: Actually, it might be a dupe of [the last one](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5662/52137), which I think is the one @Medix2 was thinking of. It also has links to several MSE requests.

Comment: @Someone Yeah that's the one. I feel like this is a duplicate though only because I can't imagine a world where you can change votes when questions are reopened or closed but not when questions are edited

Comment: ah. couldn't find that other one, and didn't check the metameta. thanks team

Comment: great minds think alike; I've closed this as a dupe for housekeeping.